# bitshifting does not propertly work for short values

Tags: java, binary, int, bit-shift, short

I've a little problem with bitshifting short values:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0b1100010001000100 >>> 12); // works correctly, output: 1100
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString( 0xFFFF & (short)(0b1100010001000100) >>> 12)) // does not work correctly, output: 1111111111111100
```

What's the problem and how can I handle it?

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, `0xFFFF & (short)(0b1100010001000100) >>> 12` means `0xFFFF & ((short)(0b1100010001000100) >>> 12)`. So the bitwise AND is last, after shifting.

There is a rule that a `short` is converted to `int` before shifting (and most other operations), so that `short` is first sign-extended to a `int`, more leading ones appear because the value is negative. If the bitwise AND happened between this implicit conversion and the shift, the extra ones would be removed:

```
(0xFFFF & (short)(0b1100010001000100)) >>> 12
```